# Why MySQL inserts wrong date?

Tags: mysql, sql

The server has local time as 19 August 17:20  (+4)

When I execute query `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTMAP()` it returns `2019-08-19 13:33:36`. It is not UTC time.

What is it? How to set time in UTC?

Why UTC current time is  `1:25 PM`, but SELECT CURRENT_TIME() `is 13:40:19`

Comment: I don't know MySQL all that well but a simple search yielded `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. That same search showed multiple sources of documentation (for the synonym `NOW()`) that seem inconsistent with the behavior your describe; it seems that the time returned should be timezone-adjusted.

Comment: _This may seem like a silly question but:_ Did you check the System time and then get distracted and wait 13 minutes to do the `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTMAP()`

Comment: System time is valid, it is local time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the current timezone to UTC before getting the current timestamp:

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: @user3573738 I've edit the post. You seem to be missing the extended time zones that I have loaded on my system. -- sorry about that.

Comment: It returns now `2019-08-19 13:57:29` Why if UTC current time now is: `1:42 PM` ?

Comment: Why I have differennce in minutes?

Comment: I have created_at field (TIMESTAMP type), it has default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it always adds wrong UTC date, difference in some minutes

Comment: @user3573738 I am not sure what you are saying. A CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column will not change values unless you created it with an 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' clause and you then update the row or you explicitly update the column. It will, however, retrieve differently depending upon the current timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),yourlocaltimezone,'UTC')
```

Comment: I am not sure, what is data Mysql inserts to DB, is it UTC or not, seems not,

Comment: And I need store in UTC then convert to local timezone

Comment: It gives `2019-08-19 13:41:04`, it is not current UTC time

Comment: Just a heads up: I imagine you copy+pasted OP's code, which has a typo (`TIMESTMAP`).

Comment: It is type, but problem is the same

Comment: I dont nee now() I have field created_at with timestamp type

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00');`

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: @RonaldAaronson `NOW()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` are identical (as is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with no parens) - they're all aliases for the same implementation. Just providing some context as to your last comment, not sure if it's *super* relevant :)

Comment: @TylerRoper My comment was trying to point out that the answer could be improved by replacing `yourlocaltimezone` with `@@session.time_zone`. Also, not all MySql servers recognize timezones such as 'UTC'.

Comment: I see, didn't have much context so I wasn't sure. Around the time of that comment, the answer was edited from `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to `NOW()`, so I just wanted to make it known (moreso to fa06 than yourself) that those are one in the same.